# inherit parent window and add an additional button in tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, class, tkinter

i'm trying to create two separate windows, one of which should inherit the others interface, and grid some additional buttons. How can I achieve this? 
Below is an example piece of  code:

```
f = ("Helvetica", 18)
bg = 'white'
g = '1400x800'

class MainUser(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        Frame.configure(self, background='white')

        self.logo = PhotoImage(file="logo.gif")
        Label(self, image=self.logo).pack()

        Button(self, text='test', bg=bg, font=f).pack()

class MainAdmin(MainUser):
    pass # What now?
```

Comment: You *cannot* "grid some additional buttons" into an instance of `MainUser`, because its existing child widgets are managed by `.pack()` - which cannot be used with `.grid()` in the same container.  If you meant that in a more generic sense, you can certainly *pack* additional buttons in the subclass, you'd just give `MainAdmin` an `.__init__()` much like `MainUser`'s (call the superclass `__init__()`, add whatever widgets you want).

Comment: @jasonharper Yes I meant in a more general case, what do you mean by call the 'superclass'. Sorry, I am new to OOP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to create a proper `__init__` that calls the same function in the superclass. Then, add widgets like you would have done in the superclass.

Example:

```
class MainAdmin(MainUser):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        another_label = Label(self, text="Hello from MainAdmin")
        another_label.pack(side="top", fill="x")
```